# Move from HTTP to HTTPS and crawling requests

Tags: seo, google, https, search

I have moved my web site from http to https, http is fully redirected to https and they are identical in content. I have added both properties to Google Search Console, when I ask Google for crawl (Fetch as Google option in Search console) do I do it for https or for http or for both?

Comment: You don't need to ask.  Googlebot is always crawling.

Comment: With "ask" I have meant - to use "Fetch as Google" option in search console

Answer (score 2):

From here on, you should only do these kind of checks (fetch-render, sitemap, crawling, mobile usability etc..) in the HTTPS version of the GSC property.

Side node: You should only monitor the HTTP property in GSC to see if traffic decreases in time. And at some point, you should have no traffic data in the HTTP property (assuming HTTP site is correctly redirected to HTTPS)

Answer (score 1):

If redirecting properly, Googlebot can't crawl the http site. If you have a fresh sitemap of the new https site, I would upload it under the https property, and check back in a few days. Always keep check for errors and suggestions that Google Search Console gives you.